# Navigate to sibling Routes's Route without page reload in React router 6

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Let me present my problem,
I have two subdomains in the same react SPA codebase, say `abc.domain.com` and `xyz.domain.com`
I've logically separated the Route block inside Routes for both subdomains.
This is my code at the root level

```
<BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          {isabcSubdomain() && <AbcSubDomainApp />}
          {isxyzSubdomain() && <XyzSubDomainApp />}
        </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Inside `AbcSubDomainApp`

```
<Routes>
    <Route path="a" element={<A/>}/>
    <Route path="b" element={<B/>}/>
</Routes>
```

Similarly, inside `XyzSubDomainApp`

```
<Routes>
    <Route path="x" element={<X/>}/>
    <Route path="y" element={<Y/>}/>
</Routes>
```

Now, I am at `abc.domain.com/a` and want to navigate to `xyz.domain.com/x` without any **page reload**, just with a button trigger (say), is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is **not possible**, but not only because it is not supported in React.

Each time a browser detects a change to a new domain (subdomains too), a request to a DNS server is triggered (it may be cached but the request is always made), and the browser will then treat the content as coming from a different source.

**This happens for very good reasons.**

1. If you were to suddenly switch domains without reloading, how would the browser know which site data to use?
2. If you switched domains without realizing, you might accidentally enter private information into the wrong website!

**I recommend you do not pursue this functionality within your website.** Having two copies of the exact same code on different websites is not a good solution.

Comment: Hi @shn, thanks for your answer. However, in my current scenario, these two subdomains do share the same session in a browser through cookies. Also, the `sub`-domain switching will be in my control, we allow access to only certain subdomains. Lastly, how is it two copies of the same code? Component  X and A are totally unrelated, it's just their codebases are the same.
Correct me please if I understood your point wrongly.

Comment: While you may use the same session within your code, as far as I know browsers do not allow this. I know that in your case it will be safe, but whenever you click a link to a different domain than is in your url bar, it is considered a `Cross Origin Request`. Sorry I mistakenly thought there were two codebases.